# Using an abstract data entity model with MVC3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

I want to be able to share the same EDMX across multiple projects in the same solution.  So I put it in its own project so that I can reference it.  The problem is that when I try to use the Controller generator in MVC3 it won't let me because the EDMX is not under the Model folder.  There has to be a simple way to fix this.  Any ideas?

Thank you,

Aaron

Comment: Does recompiling the whole solution help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep its really easy (when you know how). There is a complete walkthrough here http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/mvc3-1-scaffolding-magic-with-database-or-model-first-not-just-code-first/ from Julie Lerman.

In brief when you scaffold the controller you need to specify *both* the model and the context from your separate project to get it to work.

Comment: Thank you this totally answers my question.  Also, thanks to Julie Lerman.  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FU6xPxrEhyU&feature=player_embedded

Comment: Hey Aaron 'The Frog' Salazar, I'd be very careful making comments like that around Julie:-)